# Offline text to speech API for Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, text-to-speech

I know there's [Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service](https://translatorservice.codeplex.com/) API for WinRT, but it depends upon Internet, is there any offline Text To Speech API available for WinRT ?

Answer (score 1):

No winrt v1.0 did not have speech api.
Windows 8.1 updates winrt and brings speech

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx

Comment: Failing native support, Bing api is the option but you already knew that